# Removing a column before data analysis

Tags: python, pandas

I am attenmpting to remove the first column after importing data from an excel file.

I have tried to use the drop funcion in pandas,here is the section of code I have used.

```
file1 = file1.drop(columns=0)
```

Any pointers as to where I am making the mistake would be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, do:

```
file1 = file1.drop(file1.columns[0], 1)
```